# Question and a problem about setlocale on windows according to information on php.net

Tags: php, time, setlocale

Just a question about some information on setlocale i found on php.net
http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php

It says:

```
Note:

On Windows, setlocale(LC_ALL, '') sets the locale names from the system's regional/language settings (accessible via Control Panel).
```

Does that mean if i add setlocale(LC_ALL, '') to my php, it should be the same local as my system? Because i have done that and it's still English with months.

When i echo out setlocale(LC_ALL, 0) i get this:

```
LC_COLLATE=C;LC_CTYPE=Norwegian (Bokm�l)_Norway.1252;LC_MONETARY=C;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=C
```

and when i echo out setlocale(LC_ALL, '') i get this:

```
Norwegian (Bokm�l)_Norway.1252
```

So i don't really know what to do from the echo it looks like its set to Norwegian and when i use setlocale(LC_ALL, '') i should also set everything to Norwegian including time, but it does not.

Here is also the code i use to change the time format.

```
date('d.F', strtotime($row['date2']))
```

Comment: We don't so "SOLVED" in the title here. If you've found your own answer you can either post the answer and accept it, or delete the question.

Comment: @j08691 Sorry, diden't know. I have posted now, but it says i have to wait 2 days to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**: Use `strftime()` instead of `strtotime()`.

`strtotime` does not take into account the set locale.

**Before:**

```
date('d.F', strtotime($row['date2']))
Output: 17.February
```

**After:**

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, '');
strftime('%e.%B',strtotime($row['date2']))
Output: 17.februar
```